# Unable to find OTPCredential in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to build an OTP autoread in web. I read Chrome provides OTPCredential ([here](https://web.dev/web-otp/)). But the check `'OTPCredential' in window` fails on every mobile chrome browser I am trying even when the version is greater that 84. Have they removed the support now?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I actually may have found the problem. Are you trying to do this locally? The feature only works in secure contexts (HTTPS, etc)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OTPCredential

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not work locally, works in production(HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`navigator.credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/credentials), it returns a `Promise` resolved with the one-time password (code) when the device receives the OTP SMS message containing the requesting URL and the code:

```js
navigator.credentials.get({otp: {transport: ['sms']}})
```